# Is there a way to avoid pushing node_modules on every push using Docker?

Tags: docker, dockerfile, google-container-registry

I've got a **node_modules** folder which is **120MB+** and I'm wondering if we can somehow only push the **node_modules** folder if it has changed?

This is what my docker file looks like at the moment:

```
FROM node:6.2.0

# Create app directory
RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# Install app dependencies
COPY package.json /usr/src/app/
RUN npm install

# Bundle app source
COPY . /usr/src/app

CMD export NODE_ENV=production

EXPOSE 80:7000
# EXPOSE 7000

CMD [ "npm", "start" ]
```

So what I'm wanting to do is only push the **node_modules** folder if it has changed! I don't mind manually specifying when the node_modules folder has changed, whether I do this by passing a flag & using an if statement, I don't know?

### Use case:

1. I only made changes to my application code and didn't add any new packages.
2. I added some packages and require the node_modules folder to be pushed.

### Edit:

So I tried the following docker file which brought in some logic from

http://bitjudo.com/blog/2014/03/13/building-efficient-dockerfiles-node-dot-js/

When I run `docker built -t <name> .` with the below **Dockerfile** & then `gcloud docker -- push <url>` it will still try push my whole directory to the registry?!

```
FROM node:6.2.0

ADD package.json /tmp/package.json
RUN cd /tmp && npm install

# Create app directory
RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app && cp -a /tmp/node_modules /usr/src/app/
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# Install app dependencies
# COPY package.json /usr/src/app/
# RUN npm install

# Bundle app source
ADD . /usr/src/app

CMD export NODE_ENV=production

EXPOSE 80:7000
# EXPOSE 7000

CMD [ "npm", "start" ]
```

Output from running `gcloud docker -- push etc...`:

```
f614bb7269f3: Pushed
658140f06d81: Layer already exists
be42b5584cbf: Layer already exists
d70c0d3ee1a2: Layer already exists
5f70bf18a086: Layer already exists
d0b030d94fc0: Layer already exists
42d0ce0ecf27: Layer already exists
6ec10d9b4afb: Layer already exists
a80b5871b282: Layer already exists
d2c5e3a8d3d3: Layer already exists
4dcab49015d4: Layer already exists
```

**f614bb7269f3** is always being pushed and I can't figure out why (new to Docker). It's trying to push the whole directory which my app is in!?

Any ideas?

Comment: Is it any better with https://github.com/ryanramage/docker-build-run-push?

Answer (score 0):

This blog post explains how to cache your dependencies in subsequent builds of your image by creating a layer that can be cached as long as the package.json file hasn't changes - http://bitjudo.com/blog/2014/03/13/building-efficient-dockerfiles-node-dot-js/

This is a link to the gist code snippet - https://gist.github.com/dweinstein/9468644

Worked wonders for our node app in my organization.

Comment: This is a really good idea. But I'm unsure why it's still pushing my whole directory? See my updated question!